# Scope of CSS class

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

```
<style>
.bgClr{
background-color: lightgreen;
}
</style>

<link href=@Url.Content("~/Content/css/xyz.css") rel="stylesheet" />
<div>......
<input type="text" class="bgClr" />
....</div>
```

Here is the code I've written in my html page. 
In xyz.css, I have defined the same css class like this

```
.bgClr{
background-color: red;
} // in xyz.css
```

But in result, background-color color of the control is always Red.

May I know the reason why the .bgClr of xyz.css is always taken ?

Comment: I thought this was a beginner's question worth of downvoting until I realized that I didn't know this precisely enough myself - I always thought `<style>` would have priority over `<link>` (which it does, theoretically) but today I learned that `<link>` will still override `<style>` if it is defined after the latter. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it was attached later. If the external stylesheet is placed after the internal's, it will override all previous already defined selectors (`internals` or `externals`).

But if you have **inline styles**, they have the highest priority

Comment: That's not really accurate though, is it? Let's say I have an element that is styled inline (`style="background:red;"`) and then I add a `<style>` block at the *end* of my HTML document, trying to override that element, the inline-rule should win AFAIK.

Comment: @domdom, inline has the highest priority

Comment: Exactly. What confuses me is that I always thought `<style>` had a higher priority over `<link>`, which seems to be backed up at least by [this source](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/web/2.3.0/org.tizen.mobile.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/dom_guide/html_priorities_css.htm) - has this changed?

Comment: If you add styles via link, it goes and sets into the styles after all

Comment: Right, [the last paragraph on this page](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/510179afea2d1ce7e3000860) seems to confirm it: *"Note: If the link to the external style sheet is placed after the internal style sheet in HTML , the external style sheet will override the internal style sheet!"* - I learned something today.

Answer (score 0):

It takes the style of the stylesheets added latest in your `html`. Try placing your stylesheet link at the very top.

Answer (score 0):

The code and external links are interpreted sequentially. Which means the bottom most link will override the preceding ones.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't about scope, this is about specificity.

The definition in the file was considered a higher specificity since it was declared later.

There are a lot of other contributing factors to specificity, you can read all about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity